# Restore oracle 9i db with dbf only (after shutdown abort)

Tags: oracle

How to restore oracle 9i db with dbf only (after shutdown abort)

I have tried alter database open reset logs but it says cannot use resetlogs option before incomplete database recovery

I have tried recover the database and datafile, it seems ok. But when i try "alter database open resetlogs" again, it takes very long time and then timeout finally

Any idea on how to open an aborted shutdown oracle 9i db. Without any redo logs and archive logs?

Thanks.
Thx

Comment: What backup regimen did you use or this database? RMAN? Daily exports? Something else? Nothing? Also do you have any other files beyond the DBF FILES? I'm thinking specifically of the CTL files.

Comment: just the cold backup (shutdown abort and then backup the dbf file), but without backup the ctl file and log file.

Comment: So you don't have a regular backup? Just copies of the DBF files after you crashed the database? Oh dear. The hard lesson is, just like Word docs or photos on a hard drive, stuff which is not backed up *does not exist*. Running an obsolete version of the database without taking regular back-ups is recklessness. Which doesn't help you now but this is an important teaching, and you should learn from it. Do you have the Oracle software? Can you create a new database?

Comment: Yes, I can create a new database

Comment: Have a look at [this old IT Toolbox thread](https://it.toolbox.com/question/re-build-database-from-dbf-files-020705). It seems like a similar problem and it has a happy ending (although the thread is bit confusing).